# The XRSubreport does not contain any data when applying filter

Tags: c#, winforms, xtrareport

I have two reports the first one 'RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport' as master report and the second one 'RepDailyAssemblyProductionByEmployee' as detail report
on master report i added unbound detail band and I put in it XRSubreport and I set report source properties to detail report.i followed this instruction
[Create a Master-Detail Report with Subreports](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4629/create-popular-reports/create-a-master-detail-report-with-subreports)
both reports has stored procedure as a datasource to open the master report i use this code

```
private async void DailyProductionByEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport reportEmployee = new RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport();

        Parameter param1 = new Parameter
        {
            Name = "shifttime",
            Type = typeof(string),
            Visible = false,
            Value = form.cmbShiftTime.EditValue
        };


        Parameter param2 = new Parameter
        {
            Name = "date",
            Type = typeof(DateTime),
            Visible = false,
            Value = Convert.ToDateTime(form.FirstDate.EditValue)//.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        };

        reportEmployee.Parameters.Add(param1);
        reportEmployee.Parameters.Add(param2);

            reportEmployee.DataSource = await assembly.RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport(Convert.ToDateTime(form.FirstDate.EditValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
                                                                                     Convert.ToInt32(form.cmbShiftTime.EditValue));

            form.Close();
            reportEmployee.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
        }
```

to master report I use subreport BeforePrint event to set the datasource like so

```
private async void subRepProduction_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {

        ((XRSubreport)sender).ReportSource.DataSource = await assembly.RepAssemblyDailyProductionShiftTimeByEmployee(Convert.ToDateTime(Parameters[1].Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
                                                                         Convert.ToInt32(Parameters[0].Value));
    }
```

Now if I applying a filter I do not get any data
[image]
but when I clear the filter the some first rows does not show then all rows show then only the first row is repeated
[image]
How can I solve this problem, thanks in advance.
Update :Code that get data from sql server database

```
public async Task<DataTable> RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport(string DateProduction, int ShiftTime)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        {
            Value = DateProduction
        };

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ShiftTime", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = ShiftTime
        };

        dt = await DAL.SelectData("RepGetAsemblyEmployeeForDailyReport", param);
        DAL.Close();
        return dt;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use "async void" event handlers here
because of "fire and forget approach".
remove the async/await keywords from the "subRepProduction_BeforePrint" event handler

Comment: When I remove it I get this error:An object assigned to the DataSource property cannot be used as a report's datasource, because it does not implement any of supported interfaces

Comment: So it is your real issue. What kind of data source do you assign?

Comment: I am using stored procedure to get data from sql server database as a DataTable ,I update my question